# How to test a site for Mac on Windows

Tags: macos, cross-browser

I dont own a Mac, but a few of my users do and this becomes a problem when they report a problem with my site that ONLY THEY see. How can I get around this problem without having to buy a Mac or using a vmachine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross browser testing app like BrowserStack. It is free to use for a certain amount of minutes and limited choice of devices and browser version but it is an excellent tool to diagnose problems.

Comment: Not bad, but it has a very limited choice of browsers. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @CainNuke No problem, it is limited. The other alternative is to do a screen share with those friends, if possible, and guide them through the debugging process. A bit of a pain but it could work.

Comment: If I only had any friends hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

There are [several services which provide Mac machines](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-services-that-provide-hosted-Mac-OS-X-desktops-in-the-cloud) in cloud like:

- [Mac In Cloud](https://www.macincloud.com/)
- [Mac Stadium](https://www.macstadium.com)

Also there are [cloud cross-browser testing service providers](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/cross_browser_testing_tools/) like:

- [BrowseEmAll](https://www.browseemall.com)
- [ExperiTest](https://experitest.com/cross-browser-testing)

Unfortunately it's [illegal to install MacOS on non-Mac hardware](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX10103.pdf)

> A. Preinstalled and Single-Copy Apple Software License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, unless you obtained the Apple Software from the Mac App Store or under a volume license, maintenance or other written agreement from Apple, you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple-branded computer at any one time. For example, these single-copy license terms apply to you if you obtained the Apple Software preinstalled on Apple-branded hardware.

therefore you will not be able to use virtual machines